# is it enogh to have a single database for the entire software or any application like (if i am using MS Access database in my software)

Tags: ms-access

I'm designing a database and I have a query about how to structure tables in Microsoft Access.

I'm not sure if I should create a new database for each table I create, or put all of my tables into one database.

Here are examples of the tables I require:

```
employee_info data
machine info
billing
```

Comment: Expanded on the original question and improved grammar. It's always better to try to explain as much as you can in your question and keep it simple enough for people who are looking at your implementation for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

A single database can have multiple tables amd you can use multiple applications. There is no sense in creating multiple databases for multiple tables.